# Java Android 2.3.3, how do I load multiple data from an XML file?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-xml

I have an XML file in res/values. The file contains a list of people. This is then presented inside a listview. So far, no problems. But I want to modify my listview to also display a picture for each person and some details. The idea is something like this for the listview:

```
<row>
  Name - Picture
  <i>Description</i>
</row>
```

My question is, how can I store all that information inside my XML file? Normally that is not a problem, like:

```
<persons>
  <person name="Scott">
    <picture>path to asset somehow?</picture>
    <desciption>Description of Scott</desciption>
  </person>
  ...
</persons>
```

But how do I add this into the res/value/persons.xml file? The only thing is like a string-array and I do want Scott's description to end up with Scott and not with someone else. Is this possible or do I have to add this xml document somewhere else and then parse it somehow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if possible, it would be better to keep this data in database.......

One time work:

1- When App start check the databse "DATABSE NAME" Exist or not.
2- if not create the data base and parse the XML and put in the data base.

Repetitive work:

3- fetching and Update from/in Database is easy and efficient to then writing large data in XML again and again.

Comment: But can i deliver my app with a database inside it? and if so, what database works with android ? SQLite?

Comment: yes con do that by keeping data base inside the project and when app load first time copy it in data folder but would be fine if you keep your data initially in XML and then make the data base when your loads. and yes it would be SQLite